# WAP 1.1 javascript support

Tags: javascript, mobile, wap

Does WAP 1.1 supports javascript? I am creating a website for which plays audio content in an audio player. I want to support some old phones which support WAP 1.1. I want to know if javascript/jquery will work in those phones so that I create the audio player accordingly.